# page content not displayed in Explorer

Tags: css, explorer

The beginnings of a site here:
http://qaa.miltonfame.org/
html and css pass validation tests
Page displays fine in all Mac browsers I have tried (Safari, Firefox, Camino)
Page displays fine in Windows 7 FireFox
Nothing but background renders in Explorer 8 Windows 7 (and in other Explorer versions via screenshot services.) View Source shows that Explorer is getting the content - it's just not appearing on screen.

No idea how to approach addressing this - any suggestions would REALLY be appreciated.
Thanks a million.

Answer (score 1):

My friend, you haven't closed your script tag for jquery. I saved a local copy and tested it - the content shows up once the tag is closed.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery-link" />
```

It needs to be like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery-link"></script>
```

Cheers! :)

Also you've got a script tag and meta tag at the bottom that you may need to take care of.

Comment: DMin - thank you SO much! I was treating the script markup with the shorttag style like for img and br and link... yippee! Now it works everywhere. I really appreciate your help and expertise.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a shot in the dark and say that if you remove the following, you'd have better success:

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
        <script src="/js/ie7/IE8.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <![endif]-->
```

Since you say that HTML and CSS passes, you can pretty much rule that out.  Your source doesn't look that complicated.  That leaves JavaScript, and the only IE specific thing in your source are those lines.

Comment: Thanks Brad. I'll have a look at that. The conditional script shouldn't send the js to Explorer 8 (assuming I wrote the condition correctly) but I don't know where else to look, so will give that a shot. Not too hopeful though. Google didn't turn up much except settings users have to make to their security and there is no way I can expect users to do that - it just has to work.

:-(